# Cypress theme doesn't show notification bell

Tags: community-builder, notification, experience-builder-page

We've built an Experience/Community for a client using Salesforce's Cypress theme. Everything's great, except the notification bell doesn't appear no matter what.

[The Cypress theme thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSlDM.jpg) shows a notification bell, and there's an empty space for it in the theme's HTML, so I know it's possible. But there doesn't seem to be a setting. Adding comments to knowledge articles via Chatter generates notifications in Lightning Experience, but still nothing in the Experience/Community -- the HTML element remains stubbornly empty.

Am I missing something obvious?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314990&type=1)

Comment: @Vinay Unfortunately, no -- this theme has no such option under `Theme Settings`.